# Why quantifier-free part of a PNF formula is called matrix?

Tags: logic, terminology, math-history, quantifiers

It is well known that every QBF or first-order formula can be rewritten to a prenex normal form

$$Q_1x_1 \ldots Q_nx_n. \phi,$$

where $Q_i \in \{\forall, \exists\}$ and $\phi$ is a quantifier-free formula called the **matrix**.

For me, this name seems pretty unusual for a logical formula. So my question is why do we call $\phi$ matrix?

Comment: I think that this use of "matrix" is due to W&R's [Principia Mathematica (1910-13)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/); see [Intro, page xxii](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Principia_Mathematica_to_56/ke9yGmFy24sC) for the explanation: "Thus in $(\exists x) (y) \phi(x,y)$, "$\phi(x,y)$" is the *matrix* and "$(\exists x) (y)$" is the *prefix*. It thus appears that a matrix containing $n$ variables gives rise to $n!2^n$ propositions by taking its variables in all possible orders ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster definition of matrix](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matrix): Something within or from which something else originates, develops, or takes form.

Sounds like a reasonable description of $\phi$ in this context.

In fact, it sounds like a better use of the word "matrix" than for "a rectangular array of numbers".

Comment: Thanks! I'm not a native English speaker, and was not aware of this context.

Comment: @dvvrd Comes from the same Indo-European root as mother, maternal, etc.